# Spring MVC, Upload file with other fields

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to construct method for uploading file with some other form fields.

This is standard Html form with file and some other fields:

```
<form action="products" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Please note: I want to use standard HTML form, not Spring form tags like `<form:form ...>` etc

And this is my controller method:

```
@ResponseBody
public MyDto createProduct(@RequestBody MyDto dto, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {

}
```

But I'm getting error: `Required request body content is missing`.

How should I construct my web method to receive file as well as DTO object as arguments? Also it will be nice if I can have MultipartFile object included into `MyDto`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your issues occurs cause your body is consumed when binding the values of the first argument, by ommiting the annotation for the dto the framework will instantiated and populate the matching properties from the request values

```
  @ResponseBody
  public MyDto createProduct(MyDto dto, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {

  }
```

note also that you can add a *file* property of the type *MultipartFile* to your *MyDto* instance, it will instantiate and bind correctly as well, so just

```
@ResponseBody
public MyDto createProduct(MyDto dto) {

}
```

Comment: In this case I'm getting `Required MyDto parameter 'dto' is not present`

Comment: I've answered properly now, originally my main point was not to use *@RequestBody*, but in fact should not be replaced with *@RequestParam* either, ommiting the annotation altogheter will get you where you wanted

Comment: I am testing with Postman rest client and JSON data not mapping with JSON request i.e. all fields in MyDto mapping to null

Comment: @Anand In postman remove header "Content-Type: application/json", and it will works fine

Comment: When are the annotations required and when are they optional? They Spring docs seem to suggest that you always need to put `@RequestBody` on your params if you want to bind the incoming request to your DTO. What's the difference in annotating or not annotating the param `MyDto dto` with `@RequestBody`?

Comment: placing the multpart field into the DTO class doesn't work