# MultipartUpload of multiple files with additional info

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Is it possible to map MultiPartUpload with additional info to POJO object?

Uploading files with additional info i  can use this @RestController:

```
@PostMapping(value = "{id}/frontPage")
public void uploadContentBody(@PathVariable long id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file[], @RequestBody List<Info> orderRequests) {
   //...
}
```

WIth that, i have separated files and info. However is there a way to map it to object? E.g

```
public class FileInfo(){
   private MultipartUpload file;
   private String info;
   ...
}

  @PostMapping(value = "{id}/frontPage")
    public void createContentPage(@Valid @RequestBody List<FileInfo> request) {
        //...
    }
```

In that case what would the request look like? As it seems i have not find a way how to put file and another data together, so they can be mapped like that.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does it answer your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370435/1439560 ?

Comment: it does not seems to, i want the multipart file and its additional info to be together in one object, as when multiple files with multiple infos are uploaded, i do not have to create some mapping afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can put file and another data together with `@ModelAttribute` annotation. Please refer the following code example.

```
@PostMapping(value = "{id}/frontPage")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@PathVariable long id, @ModelAttribute FileUploadDto dto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(id+"-"+dto.getFile().getName()+"---"+dto.getId(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have created a POJO named FileUploadDto also.

```
public class FileUploadDto {
private int id;
private MultipartFile file;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public MultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}}
```

When Sending the data it should be sent as form-data. In postman it will look like this.

[image]

Please refer the curl below.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/upload/2121/frontPage'--form 'id="121"' --form 'file=@"AwesomeDocument2.pdf"'
```

Comment: however, what if i want to upload multiple files at once?

Comment: You can upload multiple files at once also.

use `private List<MultipartFile> files;` instead of `MultipartFile file;`

In Controller, you can access multiple files, by dto.getFiles().get(index)

Comment: each of the uploaded file needs to have its own additional data, this way i have multiple files with one additional data

Comment: Simlarly you can add a list with your required data as a list where the index correlates to file index. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, sending multiple files at once from angular to java, but it is problematic setting a corresponding object their..